# Android build error 'Failed to read androiddebugkey from store'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to build this open source android project but am getting this gradle build error

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':public:mbw:packageDevDebug'.
```

> Failed to read key androiddebugkey from store "/Users/tester/Downloads/wallet-master3/keystore_debug": null

At first it was saying "> File '/Users/tester/Downloads/wallet-master3/keystore_debug' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist." So i created a blank keystore_debug text file and the previous error started showing up.

What is this keystore_debug file and how do i get it?

Answer (score 2):

All Android applications require a digital signature.  Even when you just build within your IDE, you must sign the application.  This is done as part of the build process of Android Studio (and Eclipse too).

This signature exists in a certificate file.  Certificates validate your identity as the developer of the application.  These can be (a) obtained from a 3rd-party certificate authority (CA), or (b) you can generate your own using the java keytool utility.  When you do this, it is called a self-signed certificate.

For details see http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html, section "[Signing in Debug Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode)".

So the bottom line is that you need to use keytool to generate the keystone_debug file.

Comment: Thanks man. Whats the command line command to generate a keystore_debug file?

Comment: Look at the link in my answer.  It contains the command line syntax for keytool.  Search for "Here's an example of a Keytool command that generates a private key:"

Answer (score 0):

When I created a new Android project in Android Studio, it created me a new debug.keystore file.

Comment: Yes for me too; however, ever since then I've been getting the error OP had above only `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. Unsure how to proceed.